# transition-FOUC in WebKit?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, fouc, webkit-transition

WebKit just kept annoying me very much: upon page load it would animate a `transition` from the initial , browser-default, value. I had something like

```
a:link {
    color: black;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s;
}
```

but it would fade in from `color: blue`! Other properties weren't affected by the FOUC, only the `transition`s.

Unfortunately it is super hard to reproduce, I couldn't manage to jsfiddle it. My (admittedly edge) case is setup like so:

1. a "dev" version: a bunch of `<script />`s and `<style type="text/less" />`s
2. a production version: scripts and styles [H5BP](http://html5boilerplate.com/)-style concat'ed & minified (first `lessc`ed, respectively)

the FOUC would only show up in situation 2, but that stopped after I inlined the `@import`s of some stylesheets with `@font-face`s. A workaround, but it

So I guess this must have something to with load times/order?
Anybody ever encountered something like this? (I guess not.)

At the very least, maybe someday somebody will run into this problem, and find this useful.

Comment: Does this only happens in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you've put your transition before your color. By doing it that way, you've assigned the transition while the link is the default color (blue), then told it to change color (in theory).

Try putting your transitions last to keep them from transitioning from the browser default values.

Comment: good guess, but I switched the order in my example code (I'll correct that), plus, a different color was already applied, the transition would come in later with a more specific selector. Plus, the order doesn't matter: http://jsfiddle.net/2e6nF/3/ (at least I could make use of that jsfiddle...)